# Использование Drag and drop

Tags: delphi

Я использую Drag and drop **(Embarcadero® RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin)** для перетаскивания путей к папкам - в Edit.

**Но:** В коде, что ниже, можно перетягивать и файлы и папки, **а нужно, что бы можно было - только папки.**

Стандартный код, просто для теста:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, shellapi, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure draganddrop (var msg:TWMDropFiles); message WM_DROPFILES;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  dragfile: array [0..max_path] of char;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Tform1.draganddrop(var msg: TWMDRopfiles);
begin

if dragqueryfile(msg.drop,0,dragfile,max_path)> 0 then
form1.edit1.text:=dragfile;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
dragacceptfiles(handle,true);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто проверяешь, что имя соответствует папке, с помощью `FileGetAttr` или `DirectoryExists`, иначе игнорируешь